# How to read error object of exception thrown by Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

Error object is received in exception of a try catch block that calls axios function. console.log of error appears like this:

```
[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404] {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      cookie: 'JSESSIONID=undefined;',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2'
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://myserver.url/myapifunction',
    data: undefined
  },
```

There are many more lines further in this.

Questions:

1. This is not perfect JSON. How to read this?
2. In case of success (no exception), it is perfect JSON I get, having one of keys `status`. So in calling function I am just doing `returnValue.status` to know status code of Axios call. But in case of failure this whole object doesn't hold `status` key. How to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I resolved this.

Line in try catch block

```
let promiseRet = await new Promise (function( resolve, reject);
```

In case of success:

```
return promiseRet.status;
```

In case of exception:

```
const errResp = Object.assign({},err).response;
return errResp.status;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly capture the error thrown and access its properties using the error object.

```
catch (error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the response's body data by using error.response.data, something like this:

```
try {
  // do something with axios, e.g: await axios.get('abc', data)
} catch (e) {
  const {statusCode, message} = handleError(e)
  // notify user about the error
  // alert(message)
} finally {
  // close modal, stop loading status,...
}

const handleError = (e) => {
  let message
  let statusCode
  // In my case, the response body data looks like {"status": "ERROR", "description": "Input Error"}
  if (e.response && e.response.data && e.response.data.description) {
    message = e.response.data.description
    statusCode = e.response.data.status
  } else {
    console.error(e)
    message = 'Something wrong'
  }
  return {statusCode, message}
}
```

Hope this help!